# How to update a subset of a dataframe using a function to calculate the result?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, data-cleaning

New to python. I would traditionally try to iterate a 2-dimensional array via a cycle. As I understand however, performance wise, this is not recommended in python. What is the proper way to approach these relatively basic data cleansing operations?

Here's a method that runs on a dataframe and modifies it. Argument variables is a list of strings which is a filter that drives which row's numerical data need to be multiplied by a multiplier. If the method finds an empty or `-` string in the `tpsw_id_core` column, it will update it with zero in the subset. Otherwise, it will be multiplied by the mutliplier, rounded and converted to int.

```
    def multiply_values(self, variables:list, multiplier:int):
       
        for i,row in self.output_tab.iterrows():
            if row['tpsw_id_core'] in variables:
                if pd.isnull(row['tag_result']) or row['tag_result'] == "-":
                    self.df.at[i, 'tag_result'] = 0
                else:
                    self.df.at[i, 'tag_result'] = int(round(float(row['tag_result']) * multiplier, 0))
```

I've tried numerous approaches with `.loc`, `np.where` combining with apply, all unsuccessfully with various types of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mask` to select the subset and define a function to map onto the selected rows. For a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'tpsw_id_core' : ['test1', 'test2','test3', 'test2','test3', 'test1'],
                   'tag_result': [ 3, None, 99, '-', 23, None]
                       })
variables = ['test1', 'test2']
multiplier = 55

def func(x):
    if x == '-' or pd.isnull(x) :
        x = 0
    elif isinstance(x, (int, float)):
        x = int(round(float(x*multiplier)))
    return x

df['tag_result'] = df['tag_result']  \
                    .mask(df['tpsw_id_core'].isin(variables), df['tag_result'].map(func))
print(df)
```

gives:

```
  tpsw_id_core tag_result
0        test1        165
1        test2          0
2        test3         99
3        test2          0
4        test3         23
5        test1          0
```